# Regex in java for alphanumeric

Tags: java, regex

I have one string like `010000200000, 000000200000, 020000200000`. I want to create regex for this and want to check that first 2 digit will be only 01,00 & 02. And rest of the digit should be only from [0-6].

I don't want any space or any special character in this string. I try some of the regex available online but didn't help me exactly.

If anyone has any idea please kindly help.

Comment: see answers below, but mind that this is not alphanumeric, as there are no letters :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should parse them with your requirements.

```
java.util.regex.Pattern.matches("0[012][0-6]+", "010000200000");
```

The first character is always a 0, followed by 1 character that is a 0, 1 or 2, followed by at least 1 character in the 0-6 range.

Answer (score 3):

Straightforward

```
"0[012][0-6]*"
```

Start with 0, next a 0, 1 or 2, and than any amount of digits between 0 and 6.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

If the number of digits and number of segments of your string is fixed, you could use

```
(?:0[012][0-6]{10}, ){2}0[012][0-6]{10}
```

If they are not, simply

```
(?:0[012][0-6]*, )*0[012][0-6]*
```

If you actually meant the given example is three separate strings, then it's even easier:

```
0[012][0-6]{10}
```

or

```
0[012][0-6]*
```

All this uses is [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and [repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Note that these will only behave as you like when you use them with `Pattern.matches`. If not, surround them with `^...$` to make sure there is nothing else in front of or after this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.util.regex.Pattern.matches("0[0-2]{1}[3-6]{10}", "015453356543")
```

This is the what exactly needed regular expression...yes?

Comment: No. `0-2` is also allowed for the 10 trailing digits. And the `{1}` is (always) redundant.

Answer (score -1):

What about `0[0-2][0-6][0-6][0-6][0-6][0-6][0-6][0-6][0-6][0-6][0-6]`? Obviously I guessed you need a fixed length string of 12 chars, otherwise `0[0-2][0-6]+` would be ok.

Comment: fixed length can also be achieved by using quantifiers. Will make it much more readable, so yours would be `0[0-2][0-6]{10}`